# Azure VM shows different IPs

Tags: azure, networking, ip, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I have Windows **Azure VM** and public IP (**40.115.16.153**) assigned to it. However when I execute `ipconfig /all` command inside VM, **it shows me different IP** address. I'm wondering why?

[image]

Comment: VM does not connect to public IP , your guest operating system may acquire an IP address and other network details automatically from a DHCP server and provide to VM  https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_bridged_ws.html

Comment: Please read my question carefully.

Comment: though you're actually highlighting your DNS server there - your IP would be something like 10.1.0.4

Comment: It is private IP address and I need to have public one

Answer (score 1):

When you launch a VM in Azure you do not have a public IP Address attached directly to the Nic.

With a v1 (classic) VM you either connect through the Cloud Service IP, or through a Public IP attached to the VM.

In a v2 VM, all VMs need to exist within a virtual network, to which you attach a Network Interface. That interface will have an IP Address that is local to the virtual network it is a member of. Optionally you can attach a Public IP to that interface.

In both cases the external IP address is mapped to the internal address of your VM through whatever firewalling you have configured.

This is the reason that your VM does not have the same IP as the external IP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I have a problem that I can't ping no one IP that I listed. What the reason could be?

Comment: For example I can access VM through RDP program by IP - http://screencast.com/t/cF9AgQPbdNYt, but I can't ping it from my dev machine. Do you know why?

Comment: @Badfishmaan because Azure block ICMP traffic, which is the protocol that is required for ping to work.

Comment: I used following command - netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V4 echo request" dir=in action=allow enable=yes protocol=icmpv4:8,any

Comment: So I think my firewall fined tune properly

Comment: @Badfishmaan That won't solve the problem because Azure block ICMP traffic at the network level. When an ICMP packet leaves your VM it is immediately dropped. When an external ICMP comes to your VM, it is immediately dropped. There is nothing you can do about this.

Comment: I want just to setup IIS to allow access to my website from external networks (internet) via DNS name or IP address. But it doesn't allow me to to it. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: That is an entirely different problem! You need to use the external address in DNS (ignore the internal one, it is irrelevant) make sure you have port 80 configured in Azure and it will work - if you have problems post another question

Comment: Not to rain on the parade, but... this isn't a discussion forum, and there's way too much detail being discussed in comments. @Badfishmaan - either take this to chat, or ask a new question. And if it's networking / infrastructure related, it belongs on ServerFault, not StackOverflow.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I wasn't aware there was a way for a 53rep user to start a chatroom? Has that been changed recently?

Comment: @MichaelB I hadn't noticed they were < 100. They can chat, just not create a chat.